# Overloading operator==

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Guys I have some silly struct let's call it X and I also have a fnc (not a member of it) returning a pointer to this struct so it looks like so:

```
    struct  X
    {
bool operator==(const X* right)
{
//...
}
};

X* get(X* another)
{
//...
}
```

I also have line in code which 'tries' to compare pointers to those structs but the real intention is to compare those structs pointed to:

```
if (get(a) == get(b))//here obviously I have two pointers returned to be compared
{
//...
}
```

I also defined member of `X operator==(const X* right)` which suppose to work in situations aforementioned but for reason I do not understand it doesn't. How to make it work (I CANNOT change the line `if (get(a) == get(b))` and also `get` MUST return pointer).

Comment: Can't be done. Operator overloads must have a user-defined type as one of the operands. If you're required to do `get(a) == get(b)`, and `get()` is required to return a pointer, then both operands are pointers, i.e. not user-defined types. `operator==(const X* right)` would work if you could do `*get(a) == get(b)`, but you can't.

Comment: Why can't you change that line of code?

Comment: Can you explain why you have these silly requirements?

Comment: Note that what you're effectively asking is, "I want to make the line `1 == 2` sometimes return true", except that you're asking it for pointers rather than integers. Nope, built-in comparisons can't be changed, and pointer comparison is built-in.

Comment: @Steve Jessop thanks, I do understand that but I's thinking if this behaviour could be changed, now I know it can't. Another lesson learnt. Thanks to all of you for help.

Comment: Define X& get(X* another) then you can compare references.

Comment: @QuentinUK read last sentence from my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the way pointers are compared. You *must* either change the syntax of the `if` statement, or change `get()` to return a reference instead of pointer. Any other solution is going to be quite hacky.

**If you truly must live with those restrictions**, I would suggest changing `get()` to return some kind of specialized smart pointer to encapsulate this inconsistent behavior you want, with overloaded `operator ->()` and overloaded `operator ==()`. I swear though, this is really just asking for trouble, and I think you're still better to fight whatever power doesn't allow you to change the `if()` statement.

Comment: @104 do you think that unique_ptr will be ok for that? I do not have to use raw pointers so I'm  just guessing here really.

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't work: Your types are pointers, and you cannot overload the operator for built-in types. So, first off, you compare by dereference:

```
T * a, * b;

if (*a == *b) { ... }
```

Next up, to make this work, you must implement `T`'s operator:

```
struct T {
  bool operator==(const T & other) const { ... }
  /* ... */
};
```

Note that the operator should be const and take the right-hand-side argument by const reference!

To refer to your last sentence: If you both cannot change `get(a) == get(b)` **and** you also cannot change the type of `get`, then you are stuck comparing pointers.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't change the line `get(a) == get(b)` and you can't change the `get()` then what you are trying to achieve is impossible.

Overloaded operators can only be defined where at least one operand is of a user-defined type (or reference to a user-defined type). Pointers to classes don't meet that requirement so you can't define an operator that will be called where two pointers are compared.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool operator==(const X* right)
```

compares an X to an X*.  Not sure there is a way to declare a comparator for both X*, but my C++ is a little rusty, and you might give a friend method a shot.